# ContextAPI: How would one share data between contexts in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, react-context

Here's my problem:

The authentication bit of my website is "complete". After registering/signing in, user receives a cookie containing a jwt token. After it's received, UserDataContext is given the user's userid (uid) and username. The uid is used for all kinds of things on the server.

Socket.io will be used to tell the backend to do stuff from the frontend. Socket is available to react components through a react context. I have 2 contexts, UserDataContext and SocketContext. I need to track which socket is connected to which user.

I figure I'll make a SocketManager class on the server which listens for new socket connections and associates them with the user by the uid. I tried doing this with the Socket's id, but the problem with this is that the id changes on redirects/refreshes. So, I need a way to send the uid with the socket connection event. The uid is held in the UserDataContext.

How could I get the uid from UserDataContext to SocketContext? Should I merge these contexts? Is this even the right direction?

App.js -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import UserDataContextProvider from './contexts/UserDataContext.js';
import SocketContextProvider from './contexts/SocketContext.js';

import Landing from './pages/Landing.js';
import Topnav from './pages/components/global/Topnav.js';
import UserDashboard from './pages/components/consoles/UserDashboard.js';

import './Global.css';


const App = props => (
  <div>
    <UserDataContextProvider>
      <Topnav />
      <SocketContextProvider>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Landing} />
          <Route exact path='/dashboard/:id' component={UserDashboard} />
        </Switch>
      </SocketContextProvider>
    </UserDataContextProvider>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

UserDataContext.js -

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from 'react';

export const UserDataContext = createContext();

class UserDataContextProvider extends Component{
  state = {
    auth: false,
    uid: false,
    username: false
  };

  setUserData = data => {
    this.setState({uid: data.uid, username: data.tag})
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <UserDataContext.Provider value={{state: this.state, setUserData: this.setUserData}}>
        {this.props.children}
      </UserDataContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default UserDataContextProvider;
```

SocketContext.js -

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from 'react';

export const SocketContext = createContext();

import io from 'socket.io-client';
const prod = (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production");
const address = prod ? window.location.hostname : "http://localhost:8080";
const socket = io(address);

class SocketContextProvider extends Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <SocketContext.Provider value={{socket:socket}}>
        {this.props.children}
      </SocketContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default SocketContextProvider;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to nest things to the SocketContextProvider uses the user data context (or merge the two providers). You could then:

- send a special message that informs the server of the new uid when it changes, or
- send the uid in each message you send

That said, using contexts and providers is mostly useful to propagate state changes (such as user names, themes, whatnot) and not so much "live objects" such as that socket.

For your case, since you already have a module-level global for the socket, it's not a great sin to just forego the provider and context for the socket, and simply

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const prod = (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production");
const address = prod ? window.location.hostname : "http://localhost:8080";

let socket = null;

export function getSocket() {
  if(socket === null) {
    socket = io(address);
  }
  return socket;
}
```

and

```
import { getSocket } from './socket-things';

const MyComponent = () => (
  <button onClick={() => getSocket().send('foo')} />
);
```

Comment: I think I saw it used with context in a tutorial and went with it. This is a better idea. When you say it's not a "great sin", are you implying that it's a lesser sin and there's a better way to do this?

Comment: Having global state makes testing things in isolation harder. That said, this is fairly testable too, since you could add mechanisms to replace the `socket` object with something suitable.

Comment: Ps: I edited things a little to create and connect the socket only the first time it's actually needed.

Comment: If you use Sever Side Rendering, people will share the socket...

Comment: @quirimmo Well, no, clients in the web browser can't interact with the same socket object that's on the server. In OP's use case, it looks like all socket interactions are authenticated anyway.

Comment: @akk singletons are bad in SSR

Comment: @quirimmo Sure. However OP probably isn't interested in much SSR for a... chat app or similar?, so that isn't a real issue here. Either way, should OP want to do SSR later, things can always be refactored to support that, e.g. by making the `getSocket()`function return a dummy object when doing SSR.